# Access UPDATE statement in query fails to actually update

Tags: ms-access, sql-update, inner-join

The following tables exist:

[Passerine_Survey_Observation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOJHm.png)
[Species_Codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0NgF.png)

I'm trying to set the common name in Passerine_Survey_Observation with that of Species_Codes:

```
UPDATE Passerine_Survey_Observation 
INNER JOIN Species_Codes ON Passerine_Survey_Observation.SPEC_FK = Species_Codes.SPEC 
SET Passerine_Survey_Observation.Species_Common_Name = Species_Codes.COMMONNAME;
```

It says an update will occur; however, nothing changes in Passerine_Survey_Observation.

[Supposed update warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JPyG.png)

If I do this an update does occur as expected:

```
SET Passerine_Survey_Observation.Species_Common_Name = 'test'
```

Comment: Once you click on the warning OK, does it come up with a message saying so many records were updated?

Comment: No, it doesn't, @Knox

Comment: The code looks right to me.   if you replace the Species_Codes.COMMONNAME    with   'test'   similar to what you were doing, what happens?

Comment: Could there be a type mismatch where COMMONNAME can't go into the target field?  Or the size is a mismatch?   Normally this would result in a warning of so many rows were not updated due to...

Comment: Does the record count in your screenshot seem correct (i.e. is it all records in the observation table)? That would demonstrate whether the join is occurring as expected. If you show the query in Datasheet View, what does it show (you'd expect it to list the matching COMMONNAME for each of the observation records)?

Comment: Why do this? Why save CommonName into Passerine_Survey_Observation and not just retrieve when needed by query joining tables? Why duplicate data?

Comment: @Knox using 'test' sets the value for all records to 'test', as expected.Both common name fields are Short Text.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, the record count seems correct. And the query in data sheet view shows blank values for 118 (same number) of records...

Comment: @June7 This is a requirement for QA/QC of the Passerine_Survey_Observation table. The users want to have the common names shown there as a result of the query for ease of quality assurance.

Comment: Wow, it just seems like something is corrupt.   I would try a repair and compact on the data file.   If that doesn't fix it, perhaps create a new access file and recreate the tables and query to see if that works.   I haven't had a query related bug in recent versions of Access, so is the version of Office up to date?

Comment: Users don't understand what a relational database is. Why are users working directly with tables and queries (do they even know what a query is) instead of just forms and reports? This actually makes the data less reliable. If the common name is changed (spelling correction, etc) in Species_Codes then the value saved in Passerine_Survey_Observation is now 'out of sync'. Of course such correction is probably rare and it will be replaced next time the UPDATE is run but the possibility exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Knox was onto something...

This behavior occurred because the target field (Passerine_Survey_Observation.Species_Common_Name) - in Design View - was a List Box (under the Properties > Lookup tab). Setting that to Display Control = Text Box resolved the problem. Oops.

Final code:

```
UPDATE Passerine_Survey_Observation 
INNER JOIN Species_Codes ON Passerine_Survey_Observation.[SPEC_FK] = Species_Codes.[SPEC] 
SET Passerine_Survey_Observation.Species_Common_Name = Species_Codes.[COMMONNAME]
WHERE Passerine_Survey_Observation.Species_Common_Name IS NULL;
```

Comment: Just setting control as a listbox should not cause issue - I tested and UPDATE works fine. However, I never set lookups in table.